# Does joining a member thread accessing other members of its parent class in the parent's destructor result in undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

One of my coworkers claims that as soon as an object's destructor invocation begins, all accesses to the object's members done by a thread *(that's a member of the object itself)* are UB.

This implies that calling `std::thread::join` during the destructor of an object is UB if the thread is accessing any of the object's other members.

I briefly looked in the latest standard draft, under *"Object Lifetime"*, but couldn't find something that gave me a conclusive answer.

**Does the following code [*(on wandbox)*](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/GkyyR2rWhyTKXzzl) introduce *undefined behavior*?** What's the part of the standard that clarifies this interaction?

```
struct A 
{
    atomic<bool> x{true};
    thread t;

// Capturing 'this' is part of the issue.
// The idea is that accessing 'this->x' becomes invalid as soon as '~A()' is entered.
//           vvvv
    A() : t([this]
            { 
                while(x) 
                {
                    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(100)); 
                }
            }) 
    { 
    }

    ~A() 
    { 
        x = false; 
        t.join(); 
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't make any sense. Does he mean that deleting a raw member pointer in a destructor is also UB, since that is happening on a main thread or he means 2 threads executing a destructor which means a race condition and incorrect code. You should better ask him the source of his belief :)

Comment: "**[class.cdtor]/1** For an object with a non-trivial destructor, referring to any non-static member or base class of the object *after the destructor finishes execution* results in undefined behavior." Emphasis mine. This would appear to imply that accessing members before the destructor finishes execution is fine.

Comment: Think about it: _everything_ you typically do in a destructor depends on those members still being alive. The destructor doesn't have any arguments it could work on, the only thing it has is `this` so `this->` better refer to usable objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not undefined behavior.  If we look at [class.dtor]/8 we have

> After executing the body of the destructor and destroying any automatic objects allocated within the body, a destructor for class X calls the destructors for X’s direct non-variant non-static data members, the destructors for X’s direct base classes and, if X is the type of the most derived class (12.6.2), its destructor calls the destructors for X’s virtual base classes.

which states the the non-static members of the class are destroyed after the body of the destructor is ran.  That means all the members are alive in the destructor and manipulating `x` and calling `join` behave just like they would in a normal member function.  The only difference is after the body of the destructor is ran then the members themselves will be destroyed.

Answer (score 3):

Using N3337 since this question is tagged C++11.

It doesn't seem that it's undefined to access class members during the destructor execution:

> §12.7 [class.cdtor]/1
>
> For an object with a non-trivial destructor, referring to any
>   non-static member or base class of the object after the destructor
>   finishes execution results in undefined behavior.

and although it's stated that

> §12.4 [class.dtor]/15
>
> Once a destructor is invoked for an object, the object no longer exists

the following explicitly links to 12.7 when discussing objects:

> §3.8 [basic.life]/5
>
> Before the lifetime of an object has started but after the storage
>   which the object will occupy has been allocated <sup>38</sup> or,
>   after the lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which
>   the object occupied is reused or released, any pointer that refers to
>   the storage location where the object will be or was located may be
>   used but only in limited ways. For an object under construction or
>   destruction, see 12.7.